# Select and Insert Cannot save session in database base

Tags: php, sql-server, session, select, insert

how can I get the selected database into second page, And insert into another table.

Here is my first page :

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM qwerty
    WHERE ID LIKE '$id' ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "Name:" . $row['Fname'] . " " . $row['Lname'];
  } 

$_SESSION['fname']=$row['Fname'];
$_SESSION['lname']=$row['Lname']; 
?>
```

Here is my second page:

```
<?php
session_start();


   $sql="INSERT INTO login (Fname, Lname)
    VALUES
    ('{$_SESSION['fname']}','{$_SESSION['lname']}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO login set
Fname='".$_SESSION['fname']."',
Lname='".$_SESSION['lname']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look and try the following:

```
session_start();

$firstName = $_SESSION['fname'];
$lastName = $_SESSION['lname'];

$sql="INSERT INTO `login` (Fname, Lname)  VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName')";
```

Also ensure that when you populate the sessions

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "Name:" . $row['Fname'] . " " . $row['Lname'];
  } 

$_SESSION['fname']=$row['Fname']; //CHECK
$_SESSION['lname']=$row['Lname'];
```

that there are data assigned. Maybe add it in the loop. If you are looking for the last record it will be assinged anyway:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
     echo "Name:" . $row['Fname'] . " " . $row['Lname'];

     $_SESSION['fname']=$row['Fname']; //CHECK
     $_SESSION['lname']=$row['Lname'];
  }
```